# defining a fading-style directly in the fill command

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE i define a fading `monfading` with the command `\tikzfading` which is then used in the command `\fill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}
\begin{document}
  \tikzfading[name=monfading,left color=transparent!100,right color=transparent!0]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {HALLO} ;   
    \fill[draw=black,path fading=monfading,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Now, i encounter some difficulties, because my tikz picture is actually in the header of the page (i use `\RequirePackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`), and there, it seems not to remember the definition of `\tikzfading`. Therefore, i would like to put the definition of `monfading` directly in the `\fill` command. Therefore something like :

```
%Pseudocode : 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {HALLO} ;   
    \fill[draw=black,path fading={left color=transparent!100,right
    color=transparent!0},fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

How i can make this pseudo code a real code?

Comment: Couldn't you just put the `\tikzfading` command into your preamble?

Comment: it doesn't work either. The definition of monfading seems to be forgotten in the header. I could make a MWE for this, but before i was looking for a quick solution, like my pseudo-code

Comment: For this concrete example, you can just use `\fill[draw=black, path fading=west, fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1);`. Is your real fading more complicated?

Comment: Oh, i see, actually i redefined a completely standard fading, which already exists under the name `ẁest`. This is enough for me, i just needs this fading (for the moment). Thanks. But I am still interested in the general answer to the question.

Comment: oh, but i see also, that it does not solve my problem : it seems that one can not have a fading in the header. I have to post a new question.

Comment: `\tikzset{
 define fading/.code={
  \tikzfading[#1]
 }
}` allows you to define a new fading within your drawing command. Doesn't solve the header problem though, so I'm not sure if there's any utility for this.

Comment: No need to ask a new question, just edit in an example with the picture in the header for others to test.

Comment: @Jake: Nice idea.

Comment: Regarding defining a fading in the header, please try the fix I just posted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52931/86 and see if it helps.

Comment: @Jake, you might like to try that as well.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that when TikZ/PGF uses a fading it has to put the code necessary for that fading into the PDF near the start.  So it stores all of this in a token register that is processed at the end of the document using `\AtEndDocument`.  But this hook is executed *before* the last `\clearpage`.  This is a problem if the fadings are in headers or footers because these are only processed at the `\clearpage`.  So the necessary code for doing the fadings is processed too late to make it into the PDF.  The solution is to ensure that the fading stuff is done after the last page has been *fully* processed (ie shipped).  There are a number of ways to achieve this:

1. File a bug report and get TikZ/PGF changed.
2. Edit `pgfutil-latex.def` and change `\AtEndDocument{\the\pgfutil@everybye}` to `\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\the\pgfutil@everybye}`.
3. Issue a `\clearpage` before the end of the document, either manually or automatically.  If automatically, ie via `\AtEndDocument`, then put this *before* loading `tikz`.
4. Use the package [`atveryend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) and put:

   ```
   \usepackage{atveryend}
   \let\OrigAtEndDocument=\AtEndDocument
   \let\AtEndDocument=\AfterLastShipout
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \let\AtEndDocument=\OrigAtEndDocument
   ```

   at the start of the document.  Note that in the **main** TikZ/PGF code then this is the only use of `\AtEndDocument`.  A couple of the libraries also use it, notably the `external` library, and I haven't experimented with whether or not they are okay being after the `\clearpage` or not.  Experiment.
5. Use the `atveryend` package and edit `pgfutil-latex.def` and change `\AtEndDocument` to `\AfterLastShipout` (probably best to add `\RequirePackage{atveryend}` to this file as well).
6. Use one of the other solutions at [Can I hook into the end of the document but *after* the `\clearpage`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53179/86)

Here's some working code without modifying any of the TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{atveryend}
\let\OrigAtEndDocument=\AtEndDocument
\let\AtEndDocument=\AfterLastShipout
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\AtEndDocument=\OrigAtEndDocument
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}


\newpagestyle{teststyle}{
 \renewcommand{\makeheadrule}{%
  \color{blue}%
  \rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}}
   %% HEADER - depends on option
  \sethead{}%
   {}%
   {%
   \FadingSection
   }%
}

\newcommand{\FadingSection}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mabox.base)]
        \node[rectangle,baseline=current bounding
box.base,anchor=south east,inner ysep =0cm,inner xsep =0cm](mabox) at
(0,0) {\sectiontitle};
        \fill[path fading=west,fill=white] (-5,0) rectangle (0,1em);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{teststyle}
\section{ ABCD EFGH IJKLM NOPQR 1111 2222 3333 4444}
\FadingSection

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```