# Can I hook into the end of the document but *after* the `\clearpage`?

Tags: header-footer, hooks

The code for `\enddocument` begins:

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
```

I'd like to put something *after* that `\clearpage`.  What's the simplest way to do that?  Alternatively, I could put an extra `\clearpage` into the code that I want to dump there.  Is there a problem with issuing more `\clearpage`s than strictly necessary?  And would it cause problems having a `\clearpage` before the `\@checkend{document}` (could there be interactions with other stuff using the end document hook)?

The specific use case is (with apologies to those who thought I might be asking a *serious* question) TikZ/PGF.  As TeX processes a document with PGF stuff then it stores up some stuff that needs to be put at the start of the document.  It does this with a token register `\pgfutil@everybye` which gets invoked with an `\AtEndDocument{\the\pgfutil@everybye}`.  This works fine *except* if stuff is added to this list in the headers and footers of the last page - these don't seem to get added to the list in time to be added to the document (this came to light in looking at [defining a fading-style directly in the fill command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51792/86) where the questioner wanted to define a fading in a header.  There were various issues with this, and this appears to be a fairly important one.)

Comment: `\def\foo#1\clearpage{#1\clearpage<your code>}\AtEndDocument{\foo}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `atveryend` package provides

```
\AfterLastShipout{<code>}
```

From the documentation:

> The code is called after the final `\clearpage` of `\enddocument` before the main `.aux` file is closed. This is the right place to remember the last page in the `.aux` file, for instance.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit hard to test without a concrete MWE, but if you insert `\clearpage` into `\@enddocumenthook`, the second `\clearpage` coming after that should have not effect.

Provided you're not adding anything after your own `\clearpage` which will cause an empty page to be produced.

If all else fails, you can patch `\clearpage` in `\@enddocumenthook` to put something after it.

A bit vague I confess, but one would really need a test example for anything more concrete.

Answer (score 5):

The following seems to work (using `test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \let\oldclearpage\clearpage%
  \renewcommand{\clearpage}{%
    \oldclearpage
    \typeout{stuff}% Your stuff
}}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

As part of the `test.log`, showing that "your stuff" fits in before processing of `test.aux` is complete:

```
...
{c:/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
stuff
(./test.aux)
```