# Why won't \AtEndDocument execute at the *end* of the document?

Tags: hooks

I must be doing something incredibly stupid, but I've boiled it down just as far as it can go with no luck.  I'm working on a bug that's cropped up in a recent commit in [`pagectrl`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216211/17423) [`@ca7dc3`](https://github.com/vermiculus/pagectrl/tree/ca7dc3e768f1e6f369ac07be20033835f84b07e0).

I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\AtEndDocument{\typeout{wat}}

\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```

with the following log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.12.7)  9 DEC 2014 22:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input success-6.tex
(./success-6.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
)
No file success-6.aux.
\openout1 = `success-6.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
wat
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./success-6.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17 strings out of 493109
 369 string characters out of 6135004
 52967 words of memory out of 5000000
 3574 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 14i,4n,10p,120b,92s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on success-6.pdf (1 page, 11394 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

What is causing me way too much grief is this portion of the log file:

```
wat
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that `wat` is being typed out before the document even begins (`[`).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While my log file looks fine.  It seems that `wat` is getting typed out at the end of the document.  Test this with `\typeout{---> the end?}` just before the `\end{document}` and you'll set that `wat` is written to the log after `---> the end?` is written.

Comment: @A.Ellett You are correct.  What's more, I did a `git bisect` to find the bug – it's absolutely *vanished*.  I'm a little frightened, but I won't argue voodoo magic that works in my favor.

Comment: @A.Ellett If you post an answer explaining the relevant output of the logfile, I'll accept it so that this embarrassment can be buried in time as quickly as possible. :)

Comment: Seems like you understand better than me what happened.  I'm not sure my comment really warrents an answer.  :(

Comment: @A.Ellett I can write one up then :) It will have to wait until tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `\AtEndDocument` hook has been thought mainly for material to be printed at the end of a document, addresses or notes, for instance.

The package `atveryend` provides two more hooks, with self explaining names:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\AtEndDocument{\typeout{atend}}
\AfterLastShipout{\typeout{afterlastshipout}}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\typeout{atveryend}}

\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```

Here's the output on the terminal:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./veryend.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/atveryend.sty)
(./veryend.aux)
atend
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
afterlastshipout
(./veryend.aux)
atveryend
 )</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on veryend.pdf (1 page, 11397 bytes).
Transcript written on veryend.log.
```

Note that `atveryend` is typed out *after* the `.aux` file has been read in.

Answer (score 10):

`\AtEndDocument` updates `\@enddocumenthook` within the `\enddocument` macro. The following shows its location in `\enddocument` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook% <---- Hook for \AtEndDocument
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage% <---- Starts the final page builder
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

Note that `\@enddocumenthook` is executed *before* `\clearpage`, which starts the page builder. As such, `wat` is output *before* the page building starts. To have it output *after* the `\clearpage`, you can patch `\enddocument` (or follow some guidelines in [Can I hook into the end of the document but *after* the `\clearpage`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53179/5764)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\enddocument}% <cmd>
  {\clearpage}% <search>
  {\clearpage\typeout{wat}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```

The `.log` reports:

```
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
wat
```

Comment: That's some top-notch information!  Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the code is executed after the last page has been shipped out, in case of pending floats.

Comment: In the interest not duplicating code / modular design, egreg has stolen your tick – there is still very good information here! :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: That's truly unfortunate, but it's the name of the game.

Answer (score 6):

You can place your macros at end document after `\clearpage` without using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` package. First method can be used at very simple cases:

```
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\typeout{wat}}
```

This works because the second `\clearpage` (from LaTeX internals) is processed when the main vertical list includes only discardable items, i.e. no empty page is created. But this method can fail when another packages use `\AtEndDocument` and they suppose that their macros will be processed before `\clearpage`. Then you can use more robust method. Define `\afterclearpage` macro which shifts its argument after internal `\clearpage` control sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\afterclearpage#1#2\clearpage{#2\clearpage#1}
\AtEndDocument{\afterclearpage{\typeout{wat}}}

\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```