# How to define a "final slide" in a beamer template?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to define a custom template to mimick our organisation style (defined in pptx). I use the Beamer "title page" template to define my title page, works nicely.

However, I would like to define an equivalent for a "final slide" (like for example a copyright page). I can't find it in the manual, but maybe I missed it.

I now define this page in my custom template, but it requires the user of the template to call a custom command "\insertcopyrightpage". It would be much nicer if the template would enforce this.

Comment: How about using `\AtEndDocument` [or something like it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216268/114143)? That should, *enforce* the final slide. I would have tested it but since you did not provide an MWE, I'll leave the suggestion only. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos This works, of course. Was thinking so hard in "Beamer" mode that I missed the obvious solutions. If you wish to put this as an answer, I'll vote it up

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Added as an answer as I think this is the simplest way. `:D`. And btw, you could do the same for the titleslide with `\AtBeginDocument`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enforce something upon the end of the document you can use `\AtEndDocument`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtEndDocument{\begin{frame}
                  The last slide
               \end{frame}
                }

\begin{document}
\frame{Some slide}
\end{document}
```

This can be applied to @samcarter's answer as well to obtain the same result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{endpage}{%
    \begin{frame}
        The last slide
    \end{frame}
}

\AtEndDocument{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}}

\begin{document}
\frame{Some slide}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define whatever templates you like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{endpage}{%
    \begin{frame}
        bla
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{text}

\usebeamertemplate{endpage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, but this would again require "user intervention". I want the final page to be generated by the beamer class/sty not the user.

Comment: But the title page requires the same level of intervention?

Comment: Yes, but that is usually something the user doesn't forget ;-)